# getActivity() from Fragment is FragmentActivity not AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a BottomnavigationView in an AppCompatActivity that navigates between Fragments. For one of the Fragments, it's a MasterDetailFragment where you can search in that fragment and it will filter the data in the MasterFragment and you can click on the list to view the DetailFragment (all of this happens while the user is on one of the tabs in BottomNavigationView). I'm trying to use the new arch ViewModel to share the data between Master and Detail fragments: https://medium.com/@bharathkumarbachina/sharing-data-between-fragments-34afb6553380. It says to use getActivity() and share the viewmodel that way, but getActivity() is not getting the AppCompatActivity but instead is getting a FragmentActivity. Do I need to make a new MasterDetailFragmentActivity?

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` inherits from `FragmentActivity`. If you are sure that your activity is an `AppCompatActivity`, cast the value returned by `getActivity()` to be an `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 9):

AppCompatActivity is a subclass of FragmentActivity. You can cast the FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity after doing "instance of" check.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

Comment: So for example, my BaseActivity (with the Bottomnavigationview) has a fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.where_fragment_is, fragment).commit() and I click the navigation and it shows the fragment. Now my ViewModel uses getActivity() to get the ViewModel field declared in BaseActivity (since BaseActivity is the activity used to get to the fragment)? Or do I need to make a Bundle arguments and pass the arguments into the fragment to say which activity the fragment belongs in?

Comment: Same In Kotlin (activity as AppCompatActivity).startSupportActionMode(callback)